# How to parse the output received by gRPC stub client from tensorflow serving server?

Tags: python, tensorflow, stub, grpc, tensorflow-serving

I have exported a DNNClassifier model and run it on tensorflow-serving server using docker. After that I have written a python client to interact with that tensorflow-serving for new prediction.

I have written the following code to get the response from tensorflow-serving server.

```html
host, port = FLAGS.server.split(':')
  channel = implementations.insecure_channel(host, int(port))
  stub = prediction_service_pb2.beta_create_PredictionService_stub(channel)

  request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
  request.model_spec.name = FLAGS.model
  request.model_spec.signature_name = 'serving_default'

  feature_dict = {'a': _float_feature(value=400),
                  'b': _float_feature(value=5),
                  'c': _float_feature(value=200),
                  'd': _float_feature(value=30),
                  'e': _float_feature(value=60),
                  'f': _float_feature(value=5),
                  'g': _float_feature(value=7500),
                  'h': _int_feature(value=1),
                  'i': _int_feature(value=1234),
                  'j': _int_feature(value=1),
                  'k': _int_feature(value=4),
                  'l': _int_feature(value=1),
                  'm': _int_feature(value=0)}
  example= tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature_dict))
  serialized = example.SerializeToString()

  request.inputs['inputs'].CopyFrom(
        tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto(serialized, shape=[1]))

  result_future = stub.Predict.future(request, 5.0)
  print(result_future.result())
```

Now the output i m getting as my output is:-

[image]
I m not able to figure out how to parse that float_val number because that is my output. Pls help.

Comment: Did it solve your question ? If so, could you accept the answer ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do the following

```
result = stub.Predict(request, 5.0)
float_val = result.outputs['outputs'].float_val
```

Note that this method calls `stub.Predict` instead of `stub.Predict.future`

Comment: What if you have multiple values?

Answer (score 1):

In case you have more than one outputs, you do something like the following which basically creates a dictionary with keys corresponding to the outputs and values corresponding to a list of whatever the model returns.

```
results = dict()
for output in output_names:
    results[output] = response.outputs[output].float_val
```

Comment: Can you please clarify, what is the variable "output_names" on which you are iterating.

Comment: Yes - the output names is a list with your model's outputs. For example, in the screenshot provided in the question it would be something like this `output_name=['outputs']`. In case your model has more than one outputs it would be something like `output_names=['output_1', 'output_2']`. Personally I use the metadata endpoint provided by tensorflow serving to retrieve the metadata (including output names), i store the output names in a list and the I iterate over this list.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is probably [`tf.make_ndarray`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/make_ndarray), which creates a numpy array from a TensorProto (i.e. is the inverse of `tf.make_tensor_proto`). This way your output recovers the shape it is supposed to have, so building upon Jasmine's answer you can store multiple outputs in a dictionary with:

```
response = prediction_service.Predict(request, 5.0)

results = {}
for output in response.outputs.keys():
    results[output] = tf.make_ndarray(response.outputs[output])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is in addition to the answer given by `@Maxime De Bruyn`,

In predict API with multiple prediction outputs using mobilenet/inception model, the following code segment didn't work for me.

> result = stub.Predict(request, 5.0)
>
> float_val = result.outputs['outputs'].float_val
>
> print("Output: ", float_val)
>
> `Output: []`

Instead, I had to use the "prediction" key in the output.

```
result = stub.Predict(request, 5.0)
predictions = result.outputs['prediction'].float_val
print("Output: ", predictions)

Output: [0.016111543402075768, 0.2446805089712143, 0.06016387417912483, 0.12880375981330872, 0.035926613956689835, 0.026000071316957474, 0.04009509086608887, 0.35264086723327637, 0.0762331634759903, 0.019344471395015717]
```